# Vue Filtering JSON objects When API Has Limited Item Amount

Tags: javascript, json, api, filtering, axios

I am pulling a JSON Object from an API that has a capped amount at 200. What we are currently doing is pulling the first 200 like so:

```
https://testapi.com/posts.json
```

We are using pagination in this app with 10 posts per page. So once we get to page 20 the API URL will change to this:

```
 https://testapi.com/posts-2.json
```

That way we will pull the next 200 posts. The issue I am having is the best way to set it up to pull back posts when a filtering method is used. So there are filtering inputs for the user and when they are selected a JS filter method is being run on the JSON object. However I am not sure how to program the app to filter from the multiple API URLs at once and combine the results to display the filtered list of posts.

I am using Axios to pull back the data from the API.

Comment: could you share some of your tried code?

Comment: Are you ok with suggestions to other services in the answer. Or is it not possible to change services now

Comment: You aren’t going to be able to do clientside filtering if your client doesn’t have all of the data. If you have so many records that it’s necessary to paginate the data, you’re going to need to make your JSON API accept filter parameters, and have your database perform the filtering instead of the client. It’s just like how when you google something, you submit a request to google with a search term, and they do the filtering, your browser doesn’t download terabytes of search results to do the search.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Firebase Realtime](https://youtu.be/U5aeM5dvUpA) which allows you to import your database as JSON files. You can pull posts using their JavaScriptSDK (which also supports pagination from the get go):

`db.ref('posts').startAt(0).endAt(100)`

This will return your first 100 posts.

You can also filter really easily. Here's an example for getting the most viewed posts:

`var mostViewedPosts = db.ref('posts').orderByChild('metrics/views');`